# Google Drive API - Error: disabled_client

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I follow the Quickstart Tutorial: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python
Entering the URL for authentication shows the following error on the website:

> Error: disabled_client
>
> The OAuth client was disabled. Request Details
>
> ```
> cookie_policy_enforce=false
> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
> response_type=code
> redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
> access_type=offline
> client_id=1086226639551-hgv3m4atq7jmsdgie1d5t92qbo8k9b1g.apps.googleusercontent.com
> ```

I created id and secret for an "Installed Application" in the developer console:
https://console.developers.google.com/project

And selected "Other" as application type.

Any idea what causes the problem might help.

[EDIT] I just used PyDrive for authentication without problems:
https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive
So I will settle for PyDrive.